# Problem with hyperref/cleveref interaction and specially tagged equations

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, equations, cleveref

I would like to resolve the infamous warning `destination with the same identifier (name{equation.0.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored` in my MWE below.

Reading around this site, the package order seems to be correct. One solution I found was to use `hypertexnames=false` as an option for `hyperref`, which indeed fixes the links, but cannot be used in a document with front/main/backmatter, as then the page links are wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref} % don't use hypertexnames=false
\usepackage{cleveref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:special1}
  a = b \tag{*}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\label{eq:special2}
  c = d \tag{**}
\end{equation}

\Cref{eq:special1} and \cref{eq:special2}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get any warning with your MWE. Could you post a picture of the output you get?

Comment: @Jubobs The output looks fine, but the links are not working correctly. The warning is in the pdflatex output, and in the log.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86402/6865 solves the problem.